# Does Spring use Java Reflection Proxy?

Tags: spring, reflection, proxy

As for the Spring's EL resolving, it's obvious that it uses Reflection API. But when it comes to AOP part of Spring, does it use reflect.Proxy and reflect.InvokationHandler?
Seems that it does, as the native Spring's AOP capabilities are narrowed to method operations. But I'm not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Spring uses standard Java interface-based proxies by default. It also supports cglib-based proxying as well as full AspectJ-based AOP.

Have a look at the Spring reference: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-introduction-proxies.

For implementation details, have a look at the Spring source code over at Github: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/tree/master/spring-aop